# array_search does not work as expected

Tags: php, arrays, type-conversion

I have the following array :

```
$array = array (
    'a' => 'A',
    'b' => 'B',
    'c' => 'C'
);
```

I want to understand this behaviour :

```
// true, normal behaviour, there is a 'A' value in my array
echo array_search('A', $array) === 'a';

// true, normal behaviour, there is no 1 value in my array
echo array_search(1, $array) === false;

// true ???? there is no 0 as value in my array
echo array_search(0, $array) === 'a';
```

Why does `array_search(0, $array)` return the first key of my array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FROM PHP DOC

> If the third parameter **strict** is set to **TRUE** then the array_search() function will search for **identical elements** in the haystack. This means it will also check the types of the needle in the haystack, and objects must be the same instance.

Most people don't know `array_search` uses `==` by default If you want to search for identical element you need to add a strict parameter ... what do i mean ?

If you use

```
array_search(0, $array) //it would use == and 0 == 'A'
```

What you need is

```
array_search(0, $array,true) // it would compare with === 0 !== 'A'
                         ^------------ Strict
```

Comment: I just checked, 'A' == 0 you're right. Strange behaviour.

Comment: `var_dump(0 == 'A');` would be `true` due to type conversion

Comment: The behavior is explained here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php (first example: `0 == "a"`)

Comment: OK i remember it. That's like an `atoi` in C, "123string" will be converted to 123. That's ok! Thanks.

Comment: Yeah `var_dump(123 == "123string");` is true .....

Comment: If you want to search for 0, put it in quotes: `array_search('0', $array,true)`

Comment: `var_dump("0" == "A");` would be false even without strict option